# Word Add-n fails to call functions in home.js from <iframe>

Tags: office-js

I hava some pages in my web app, and I want use it in my Word Add-in.

So, I use it like this:

```
home.html
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function functionTest() {
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe src="http://172.16.124.16:7088/mypage.html" height="300" width="300"></iframe>
</body>
```

But I need use some functions in home.js, for example `functionTest()`, from `mypage.html` like this :

```
mypage.html
function testIframeFunction() {
    try {
        window.parent.functionTest();
        console.log('from open-word.html');
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

This isn't working on the Desktop, only in a browser.

Is there some config in VS2017 to do this?

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Where is your home.html page running?  Is it on localhost, or on this same 172.16.124.16?

In case of the latter, you need to make sure to add that domain to the AppDomains section of the add-in manifest.

Note, too, that add-ins should always use https, which means that supporting pages/files must also be on https.  In reality, you can test fine in desktop with just http, but you need https to run in Office Online (and to be accepted into the Office Store, when you're ready for that...)

Comment: OK. Now, home.html page is running on localhost, and http is just for test. Do you mean that If I want use <iframe>, home.html and these pages must in the same server?

Comment: `<AppDomains> <AppDomain>http://172.16.124.16</AppDomain></AppDomains>` when I change this in the manifest, vs gives me this massage : `{description: "permission denied", message: "permission denied", name: "TypeError", number: -2146828218}`

Comment: Is your localhost https, though?  If so, then the https-ness of the site must match that of the external resource.

Comment: Https, yes, debug in vs2017, it is default use https. The external resource is using http, not https. You mean that when the external resource using http, I should use http in localhost too? But I cannot find how to config it in vs2017...

Comment: Yes, the mismatch is probably what is causing the problem. You can disable a https by bringing up the property pane (F4) on the web project.  The ultimately, you probably want to do it the other way around, of having the external resource support HTTPS

Comment: I disable https in localhost, but it didn't work either. After some deep research, I thought it may cause by CORS issuse. Very confused now.